# Remove duplicates from a list in-place

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unique

How can one make a list contain only unique items while preserving order AND updating it in-place?

I know that a set can be used, but it will not guarantee ordering.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? A little explanation would help. Thanks!

Comment: `a = np.array(your_list);b,c =np.unique(a,return_index=True);a[c.sort()]` should solve your question

Comment: @Onyambu That is not even close to being readable.

Comment: what do you mean not readable? you need to import the numpy module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a supporting set, and a while loop:

```
def unique(arr):
    tmp_set = set()
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr):
        if arr[i] in tmp_set:
            del arr[i]
        else:
            tmp_set.add(arr[i])
            i += 1
```

The above will update the array in-place, and preserve ordering of the elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

another way without sets:

```
def deduplicate_in_place(items):
    _tmp_list = []
    for item in items:
        if item not in _tmp_list:
            _tmp_list.append(item)
    items[:] = _tmp_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Enhanced CodeSpeed solution.

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]

seen = set()

length = len(lst) - 1

i = 0
while i < length:
    if lst[i] in seen:
        del lst[i]
        i -= 1
    seen.add(lst[i])
    i += 1
    length = len(lst)

print(lst)
```

Comment: Also, this is far too complex and wastes resources.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `loop` to iter over the entries in the list one by one and insert them into a new`list` only if they are not present in the new `list`.

```
lst = [3,3,3,1,2,2,4]

my_list = []

for i in lst:
    if i not in my_list:
        my_list.append(i)
my_list

# Output - [3, 1, 2, 4]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't do it in-place. Also, I have the solution already - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587456/2274894